# PhpStorm doesn't understand '..'

Tags: php, ide, directory, phpstorm

In my code I refer to upper directory. Interpreter have not problem with path `"../app/config/config.php"` and website works, but `PhpStorm` regards it as mistake. I have a lot of warnings because of it.

There is a code form `public/index.php` [in this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKfPW.jpg) (generated by Phalcon devtools). You can see 'app' is highlighted (Path [...] not found). I have no idea how to repair this.

Comment: Just disable that particular inspection. See comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35537236/phpstorm-cant-locate-folder . Alternatively -- try using `__DIR__`, `dirname()` instead of `realpath('..')` -- IDE can calculate such stuff more reliably..

Answer (score 0):

Check phpstorm's relative path:

Ctrl + Space + Space

Hold Ctrl and press Space twice...

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the redundant '/' before 'app'. I mean the line must become:

`$config = include APP_PATH. 'app/config/config.php`;